# Round up decimal point to next value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to get a next value if the current value has decimal point(.1 to .9. not .0) with JavaScript.

Lets say:

```
var allRecords = 214;
var totalRecordSinglePage = 10;
var totalPages = (allRecords / totalRecordSinglePage)
```

> Now the value of
>
> ```
> totalPages = 21.4
> ```

But I want to convert 21.4 into 22.

> So new value of
>
> ```
> totalPages = 22
> ```

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: So [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the ceiling function: `Math.ceil(totalPages);`

More detail here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

Answer (score 1):

`Math.ceil()` is the function you need.

```
var totalPages = Math.ceil(allRecords / totalRecordSinglePage);
```

Comment: you smart, you very smart

Comment: ?? two answers posted at the same time.

Comment: yeah haha, like 1s difference between us

Answer (score 1):

Use    `Math.ceil(x)`, where x is the number.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.ceil` does exactly that.

```
Math.ceil(allRecords / totalRecordSinglePage)
```